# Extract number between two dashes in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, extract

I have a `varchar` variable in format of Letter-Number-Letter.

For example:

```
DECLARE @SerialNumber1 VARCHAR(10) = 'X-15-Y'
```

I want to extract 15 out of it.

Comment: Is it always a single letter at the beginning and end of the string? If so, dropping the first and last two characters would seem to be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the number by using the `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` functions.  First, get the first position of the hyphen using `CHARINDEX('-', @SerialNumber1)`. Use this value as the starting position for the `SUBSTRING` function and to calculate the length to the next hyphen. Example below:

```
DECLARE @SerialNumber1 VARCHAR(10) = 'X-15-Y';
DECLARE @Pos INT = CHARINDEX('-', @SerialNumber1) + 1;
PRINT SUBSTRING(@SerialNumber1, @Pos, CHARINDEX('-', @SerialNumber1, @Pos) - (@Pos));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: @Degs35 Unfortunately this will not work for the string 'X- 5 - 15-Y'.

Comment: @SurajKumar, You can just trim the result of white spaces with the TRIM function _or_ cast the result to an integer with the CAST function which will remove whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most efficient function we have in T-SQL is the PARSENAME function. In cases that we need to split string A by another string B, and if String B exists not more then  3 times (meaning we can only use this trick if the result does not include more than 4 parts), then we can use the combination of replace string B with dot and use the PARSENAME function.

For example this can be used to split IP "127.0.0.1" and get each part directly, or we can use it to get the country code (972 Israel) in phone which has the format 972-00000000, and so on...

In this question string A is 'X-15-Y' and string B is '-', therefore if this is the exact format then we can use:

> SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE (@SerialNumber1,'-','.'),2)

Comment: Check performance - this is probably the best solution for this specific case

Comment: Using `PARSENAME()` for such issues is a really bad idea... Especially if the count of items is not fixed (see comments at other answers). I just posted a generic, type- and position-safe solution.

Comment: @Shnugo According to my tests you are wrong in a big way. But before tests: (1) I explicitly mentioned the limitation of amount of items! We do not solve theoretical case but a simple explicit case. The sentence "`Especially if the count of items...`" is totally not relevant. In this case we were told that the format is consistent and the same. (2) In your solution you get all parts of the text while the question was "Extract number between two dashes in T-SQL". If you need to get all parts then AGAIN you change the requirement, and therefore you might change the best solution.

Comment: [I uploaded a basic test](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/245/Extract-value-between-two-dashes-in-T-SQL.aspx), since I do not have time right now. I do not rule out the possibility that further tests or different tests or tests under different conditions will show different results, but I will be supersize to see different conclusions using this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the numbers are between hyphens (- ) you can use string split and declaring the separator to be a dash , this will give you a result of 3 rows (1st row are the first characters before the first dash, second are the numbers after the first dash and third would be the last set of characters after the second dash) a simple where clause to select the numeric results from the string split row results should do the trick.

```
DECLARE @str varchar(20) = 'abc-013-xyz'
SELECT "value" from string_split(@str, '-')
WHERE "value" like '%[0-9]%';
```

Comment: Good day Gospodin, Well done for helping others. With that being said, your following statement is wrong: `"1st row are the first characters before the first dash, second are..."`, since the function string_split does not guarantee to return the result in specific order. This is well documented.

Comment: You are correct , I didn't intend to be precise with the 'order' of results that would come first , simply put it in order to visualize the process.

Comment: Solving this without *being precise with the order* is no solution... I'm pretty sure, that the OP would not be happy with a different order... I just posted a generic, type- and position-safe solution.

Comment: There is no order requirement, the split_string shall produce rows based on the separator and we will select only numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of extracting a number using [PATINDEX IN SQL SERVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) from an alphanumeric word is as given below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT

    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '')
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
        END
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('X-15-Y') AS NumberFromString;
```

Another way of doing extraction without creating a function is as shown below.

```
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
DECLARE @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(20) = 'X-15-Y'

SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '')
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    END
END

SELECT ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0) AS NumberFromString
```

Comment: SQL Scalar UDFs are slow, especially when using mutable variables. This function will be slow, prevent parallel execution plans and is needlessly complex for something this simple.

Comment: @AlanBurstein that's true but for using for a column either you need to while loop, cursor or function for multiple values at a time. However I have updated answer with additional part without function.

Comment: `"SQL Scalar UDFs are slow"` : Actually @AlanBurstein this is not necessarily true. The world does not stand and SQL Server evolve in time. As of SQL Server 2019 we can have Inline Scalar UDF. This still will not make this solution recommended for other reasons, but "SQL Scalar UDFs are NOT NECESSARILY slow" anymore.

Comment: RonenAriely Yes - better in 2019 but NOT with a mutable variable (which is why I called that out). You can't inline a UDF in 2019 when you change the value of a variable. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#requirements ... Note: >> SELECT with variable accumulation/aggregation (for example, SELECT @val += col1 FROM table1) is not supported for inlining.

Comment: @RonenAriely see above ^^^ (could not include 2X "at" signs)

Comment: @SurajKumar You don't need a loop for this. See my answer.

Comment: `"Yes - better in 2019 but NOT with a mutable variable"` : It is true obviously that not all Scalar functions can be converted to Inline function . I only responded on the general statement `"SQL Scalar UDFs are slow"` and I am sure you already knew it, but others might not :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, type and position safe approach should be one of these.

```
DECLARE @SerialNumber1 VARCHAR(10) = 'X-15-Y';
```

--needs SQL Server 2016+

```
SELECT A.*
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[["',REPLACE(@SerialNumber1,'-','","'),'"]]')) 
WITH (FirstItem NVARCHAR(10) '$[0]'
     ,SecondItem INT '$[1]'
     ,ThirdItem NVARCHAR(10) '$[2]') A;
```

--works from v2005

```
SELECT frgmt.value('(x/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') FirstFragment
      ,frgmt.value('(x/text())[2]','int') SecondFragment
      ,frgmt.value('(x/text())[3]','nvarchar(max)') ThirdFragment
FROM (SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(@SerialNumber1,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))  A(frgmt);
```

The first uses JSON to split the string and get each fragment by its (zero-based) position in a typesafe way.

The second uses XML to split the string and get each framgent by its (1-based) position in a typesafe way.

### UPDATE - Performance

Thanks to Ronen Ariely I thought twice about performance:

And I thought twice about the real question and my solution. My solution is not really returning what was asked for (Ronen, you are correct in this point). Picking just the number out of the string is something else...

Now to the performance and some words about `PARSENAME()`. This function **is not meant to split strings!**. It is a dinosaur and was designed to split 4-part names (such as `ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`) and proofed to be handy with version numbers (such as `1.4.3.43`) or IP-addresses. The reverse position index makes it difficult with strings with non-fixed part counts. It is very counter-intuitive...

Even if `PARSENAME()` can be used to solve this (and seems to be the best performing solution here), I would not suggest to use it. Tomorrow the product code might look differently and you'll have to re-write the whole thing entirely... This function can be a hack in very special situations. In general it is the wrong tool for splitting string.

To be honest: SQL-Server is the wrong tool with string manipulations anyway. There are some pretty good hacks, but such issues are better solved with a coding approach.

### A comprehensive test scenario

Try this, but be carefull with the last `DROP DATABASE` statement!

```
USE master;
CREATE DATABASE TestDb;
GO
USE TestDb;
GO
--create a table for some test strings
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT IDENTITY,ThreePartString VARCHAR(100));
GO
--fill the table with different codes
WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS (SELECT TOP 26 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values )
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ThreePartString)
SELECT CONCAT(CHAR(64+t1.Nmbr),'-',t2.Nmbr,'-',CHAR(64+t3.Nmbr))
FROM Tally t1
CROSS JOIN Tally t2
CROSS JOIN Tally t3
GO
```

--First - to avoid bias by cached results - start with an empty table

```
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
```

--We set the current time and measure the difference

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2;
```

--Simple string cutting with `CHARINDEX`

```
SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT ThreePartString AS OrigString
      ,CAST(SUBSTRING(ThreePartString,PosAfterFirstDash,CHARINDEX('-',ThreePartString,PosAfterFirstDash)-PosAfterFirstDash) AS INT) AS TheNumber
INTO dbo.Result1
FROM dbo.Test
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('-',ThreePartString)+1)A(PosAfterFirstDash);
PRINT CONCAT('CHARINDEX: ',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),'ms')
```

--Using `PARSENAME`

```
SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT ThreePartString AS OrigString
      ,CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(ThreePartString,'-','.'),2) AS INT) AS TheNumber
INTO dbo.Result2
FROM dbo.Test;
PRINT CONCAT('PARSENAME(): ',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),'ms')
```

--Use JSON (needs v2016+)

```
SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT ThreePartString AS OrigString
      ,CAST(JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(ThreePartString,'-','","'),'"]'),'$[1]') AS INT) AS TheNumber
INTO dbo.Result3
FROM dbo.Test;
PRINT CONCAT('JSON_VALUE: ',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),'ms')
```

--Use XML

```
SET @d=SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT ThreePartString AS OrigString
      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(ThreePartString,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]/text()[1]','int') AS TheNumber
INTO dbo.Result4
FROM dbo.Test;
PRINT CONCAT('XML: ',DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()),'ms')
GO
```

--Check for correct result

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Result1;
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Result2;
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Result3;
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Result4;
GO
```

--Clean up

```
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASe TestDb; --Carefull with real data!
```

### My measurements

On my system I get the CHARDINDEX with 43ms, PARSENAME with 20ms, JSON with 25ms and XML after 208ms.

So yes, `PARSENAME` is the fastest, but the gap is not that big, at least with CHARINDEX and JSON.

My general advise is: Starting with v2016 I'd prefer JSON for string splitting, before v2016 I'd use *normal string methods* (in connection with `CROSS APPLY` for readability) or XML. I would avoid PARSENAME if I do not need the very last millisecond.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend to [test performance](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/245/Extract-value-between-two-dashes-in-T-SQL.aspx) before you choose the solution. If you have other tests with different conclusions then please inform me and I will add it.

Comment: @RonenAriely Thanks for your remarks and your thorough test approach. See my update section.

Comment: PARSENAME is very important and highly needed function which is designed to parse SQL Server 4 parts names (not related to numbers). In SQL Server we have 4 parts name which we can use like `[Server Name].[Database Name].[Schema Name].[Object Name]`. PARSENAME  is the way we (and the server internally in some cases) parse the name and get one or more of the parts. This is why it called PARSE-NAME, and this is why it is limitted to 4 parts only. We can use this function for other uses as a trick like in my solution here 

Comment: From the documentation : [Returns the specified part of an object name. The parts of an object that can be retrieved are the object name, owner name, database name, and server name.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql)... and in this question the solution I provided is using a small trick and it should be the right answer - using PARSENAME. But as I wrote in my original answer, for other questions there are other solutions :-)

Comment: @RonenAriely Okay, you are right about PARSENAME and its original meaning, I changed this in my answer (shame on me  ). But I stick to the point that PARSENAME is the wrong approach to split a string (although it is good in this case). Happy Coding!

Comment: Happy Coding @Shnugo 

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the late entry but I also wanted to use this for response to a comment. For this you could simply use CHARINDEX and APPLY like so:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'X-15-Y';

SELECT      
  NewString = SUBSTRING(@String,d1.D,d2.D-d1.D)
FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1))    AS d1(D)  -- First Delim
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',@String,d1.D))) AS d2(D); -- Second Delim
```

That said, DON'T use a scalar udf (or any function that includes BEGIN/END -{some 2019 exceptions}). For a function that strips non-numeric characters use [DigitsOnlyEE](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/digitsonlyee-and-alphanumericonly); it's the fastest in the game and [well tested](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/do-you-have-a-stripnonnumeric-itvf-function). Here's a performance test:

```
-- Sample Data
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#strings','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #strings;
SELECT TOP (10000) s = REPLICATE(NEWID(),5) -- 10K rows of 1800 random hex chars (0-9, A-F)
INTO  #strings
FROM  sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

-- PERFORMANCE TEST
PRINT CHAR(13)+'Scalar UDF'+CHAR(13)+REPLICATE('-',90);
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(256);
  SELECT @x = dbo.udf_GetNumeric(s.s)
  FROM   #strings AS s;
PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3

PRINT CHAR(13)+'Inline Serial'+CHAR(13)+REPLICATE('-',90);
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(256);
  SELECT @x = do.DigitsOnly
  FROM   #strings AS s
  CROSS APPLY dbo.digitsOnlyEE(s.s) AS do
  OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3

PRINT CHAR(13)+'Inline Parallel'+CHAR(13)+REPLICATE('-',90);
GO
DECLARE @st DATETIME = GETDATE(), @x VARCHAR(256);
  SELECT @x = do.DigitsOnly
  FROM   #strings AS s
  CROSS APPLY dbo.digitsOnlyEE(s.s) AS do
  OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);
PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 3
```

And the results.

```
Scalar UDF
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
2257
1850
1994
Batch execution completed 3 times.

Inline Serial
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
490
487
480
Batch execution completed 3 times.

Inline Parallel
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
130
126
137
Batch execution completed 3 times.
```

The inline version is ***4 times as fast*** with a serial plan, ***20 Times as fast*** with a parallel plan.